# AlertController appears twice when saving video

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is my code:

```
            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

            library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSURL(string: path), completionBlock: { (url, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    let error = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message:
                        "Your video is NOT saved!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    error.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Shit!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler:
                        { action in navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true) }))
                    self.presentViewController(error, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Done!", message:
                        "Your video is saved!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nice!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler:
                        { action in navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true) }))
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
```

And the AlertController that says that video is saved appears twice if I press "OK" really fast (If I wait a few seconds everything is fine). What's the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: you could disable the button for 2 seconds after each press